# Tree of paths from a vertex in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Given a directed graph $G=(V,E)$, and one of its vertices $v\in V$, the set of finite paths in $G$ that start with $v$ can be seen as a tree, if we merge paths with a common prefix.

That tree is not necessarily a subgraph of $G$: if $G$ has cycles, paths can visit vertices several times, so the tree could be infinite for finite $G$.

Question: what would you call that tree?

Answer (score 1):

1. Here is a recent paper that seems to be exactly what you want in the undirected case, but may or may not be a good paper: [Nonbacktracking expansion of finite graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.05380.pdf). They call it the "nonbacktracking expansion." Excerpt from the abstract:

   > ... For an arbitrary finite, connected, undirected graph we construct
   >   an infinite tree having the same local structural properties as this finite graph, when observed by
   >   a nonbacktracking walker. Formally excluding the boundary, this infinite tree is a generalization of
   >   the Bethe lattice. ...

   The lack of good references strikes me as a red flag, and I feel there should be a better reference out there, but maybe it is one place to start.
2. Let $\text{Tree}(G,v)$ denote the tree of paths in $G$ starting from vertex $v$, which you define in your post. The map $(G,v) \mapsto \text{Tree}(G,v)$ is a functor from the category of directed rooted graphs to itself.
3. Maybe there is some nice model-theoretic characterization of $\text{Tree}(G,v)$: Consider the theory $\mathcal{T}$ over the language of a single binary relation $E$ (directed edge relation), defined by $\mathcal{T} = \{\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_3, \ldots\}$, where $\varphi_i$ says "there are no $i$-cycles". $\mathcal{T}$ is the theory of directed acylic graphs. Let $\mathcal{T}_n = \{\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n\}$. Then for any $G, v$ and any $n$, there exists $G_n, v_n$ such that $\text{Tree}(G,v) = \text{Tree}(G_n, v_n)$ and $G_n \vDash \mathcal{T}_n$. So the $\text{Tree}$ graph in a way extracts first-order information from $G$ that is not a result of $G$ having cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the interesting thoughts!  We’re actually looking at these graphs and trees in the context of RDF data and SPARQL queries so the model theoretic angle may well become useful. We do have cycles though, and labels, and two kinds of vertices, so it’s all very messy.